# How to get millisecond value of a timestamp

Tags: go, time

Go has methods to extract almost every component of a timestamp, eg `time.Second()`, `time.Nano()`, but none to extract the millisecond portion of a timestamp.

How does one extract the millisecond value of a timestamp.

eg, in the case of a timestamp like:

```
2021-01-07 10:33:06.511
```

i want to extract `511`

Comment: @mkopriva better to use `time.Millisecond` constant value insted of `1000_000`. It is more explicit

Comment: Updated version as per @DanielHornik's comment: https://play.golang.org/p/ambNkD_apB2

Answer (score 6):

To access the fraction seconds, you may use [`time.Nanosecond()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Nanosecond). And if we convert it to [`time.Duration`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration) (`time.Duration` is exactly the nanoseconds count), we can take advantage of its [`Duration.Milliseconds()`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration.Milliseconds) method (which of course does no magic but code will be clearer and easier to read):

```
func extractMs(t time.Time) int64 {
    return time.Duration(t.Nanosecond()).Milliseconds()
}
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/04YLGwTmcZO).

Answer (score 3):

there is an answer in the comments, but i want to post here to be cannonical:

```golang
func extractMillisecond(t time.Time) int {
    ms := time.Duration(t.Nanosecond()) / time.Millisecond
    return int(ms)
}
```

Comment: You can shorten this to:  `return t.Nanosecond() / int64(time.Millisecond)`, and eliminate one type conversion.